# c# || I need a variable to control another variable but both countain their own ranges. How could i do that?

Tags: c#

I'm just getting started with coding and i am not really an exact sciences guy. I'm sorry if this is too basic, but i'm really stumped on this one. I don't even know where to start and a google search hasn't lead me anywhere.

Basically, i've got one variable controlable by the player that goes from 0 to 100, and i've got another one that controls other things that goes from 10 to 140. What i need to do is for 0 on the player controlled one to be the 10 on the other one, 100 to be 140, and everything in between.

As an example of what i need i've made this absolute madman code that sort of mimics the results i want:

```
        if (getThrottle == 0) 
    {
        speed = 10;
    }
    else if (getThrottle == 30)
    {
        speed = 50;
    }
    else if (getThrottle == 50)
    {
        speed = 80;
    }
    else if (getThrottle == 70)
    {
        speed = 110;
    }
    else if (getThrottle == 100)
    {
        speed = 140;
    }
```

I'd love if anyone can point me in the right direction to what i need to get this done right.

Comment: use `||` and `<`.

Comment: A little off topic, but you should be using a switch statement, and "getThrottle" is not a proper naming convention for a variable. Just use "throttle". Happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `speed` a calculated property:

```
private double getThrottle = 50;

// Throttle ranges
private double minThrottle = 0;
private double maxThrottle = 100;

// speed range to normalize to
private double minSpeed = 10;
private double maxSpeed = 140;

// taken from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281162/scale-a-number-between-a-range
public double speed => getThrottle - minThrottle / maxThrottle-minThrottle * (maxSpeed-minSpeed) + minSpeed;
```

Comment: As a private variable, it should just be "_throttle". Common conventions exist for a reason.

Comment: @Krythic I was following OP's example, they said they are new and as such I don't want to confuse them by blasting them about the correct/common conventions

Comment: Completely understandable.

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot! I would never get into this equation by myself.

Comment: @PatrickPereira its incredibly useful formula! I too have used it in game dev.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some condition statement:

```
if (getThrottle >= 0 && getThrottle < 30) 
{
    speed = 10;
}
else if (getThrottle >= 30 && getThrottle < 50)
{
    speed = 50;
}
else if (getThrottle >= 50 && getThrottle < 70)
{
    speed = 80;
}
else if (getThrottle >= 70 && getThrottle < 100 )
{
    speed = 110;
}
else 
{   // for >1000
    speed = 140;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public const double MAX_THROTTLE = 100;
public const double MAX_SPEED = 140;

private double throttle;
public double Throttle
{
    get { return throttle; }
    set { throttle = value; }
}

private double speed;
public double Speed
{
    get
    {
    if (Throttle < 30)
    {
        speed = 10;
    }
    else if (Throttle >= 30 Throttle < 50)
    {
        speed = 50;
    }
    else if (Throttle >= 50 && Throttle < 70)
    {
        speed = 80;
    }
    else if (Throttle >= 70 && Throttle < 100)
    {
        speed = 110;
    }
    else if (Throttle >= MAX_THROTTLE)
    {
        speed = MAX_SPEED;
    }
    return speed;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per  @minijack's answer, use equation as much as possible but when relationship can't be described with an equation then instead of writing a long if else if statement, you could use **Range Tree** ; that requires you to build/populate your lookup reference just once in the class and then a simple lookup could do the job. There is already a nuget package available to do that. Code sample/example using nuget library [here](https://github.com/mbuchetics/RangeTree)

If you are interested in implementation detail of how RangeTree is created then simply brows above link's code.